# When is a good time to visit Fethiye (Turkey) to see spring flowers and have good weather?

Tags: turkey, weather-and-climate, seasonal, vegetation

We wish to:

- Have a relaxing holiday
- Not to have to take our waterproofs out with us
- See the spring flowers
- Sit outside to eat

We went at the end of September a few years ago and had 1 good week of weather but the 2nd week had lots of storms.    Therefore we don’t wish to go too early in the year to avoid the risk of storms.

(Also for some reason hotel prices seem a lot more in April then May.)

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fethiye) there are an average of 9 rainy days in March, 8 in April and 4.4 in May.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is unfortunately (along with Autumn) the [rainy season in Fethiye](http://wikitravel.org/en/Fethiye).

Some flowers bloom earlier than others, so depending on when you go, you may see a variety of different flowers.  April and May tend to be the [recommended months](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g298031-i1222-k5767375-Spring_flowers-Fethiye_Mugla_Province_Turkish_Aegean_Coast.html) as they have slightly less rain than March, and you can usually guarantee that by then the flowers will be out, however the later you leave it, the slightly increased chance of summer arriving early and the blossoms vanishing.

However, [a solid review of the tulips and flowers](http://www.turkeysforlife.com/2012/03/fethiye-in-bloom-photo-story.html) showed them in early March.  So to some extent it's a bit of a luck of the draw.

Basically, the later you go, the better chance of good weather, but the slightly less chance of seeing flowers.

To go for the best 'chance' of both, I guess that would average out to be early April then.

Comment: Thanks, shame my wife has now decided that Turkey is not safe as there is a war going on in the next county that *may* effect Turkey by next spring.

Comment: @IanRingrose ah well, fortunately spring comes every year, so hopefully things settle down.

Comment: Or the cost of last minute flights and hotels will be reasonable next spring.